# How the parent View-Model will gain access to the child View-Model?

Tags: prism, uno, winui-3

```
<Page x:Class="ParentView">
    <view:ChildView/>
    <view:ChildView/>
    ...
</Page>
```

Prism attaching the child View-Models as `AutowireViewModel=True`. How can I gain access from `ParentViewModel` to the child View-Models ? (They are actually fabricated in one factory delegate that configured in the IoC container.)

```
protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved);
```

method isn't available in `Page` control, which could have been invoked upon a `UIElement` is added ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I gain access from `ParentViewModel` to the child View-Models ?

The easiest way is to go the other way round: make the parent view model create the child view models, expose them as a collection-valued property, bind that to an items control and map the items to views through data templates. Everything else is unnecessarily complex and more or less hacky.

Use `AutowireViewModel=true` where it makes sense (i.e. if you want to use Prism's navigation), not everywhere just because you can.